# join same table multiple times

Tags: mysql, join

I would like to use sub query(which takes different inputs)multiple times and join with the parent query.here the problem is,the query takes several minutes to execute.what's the best way to optimize the following query.

```
SELECT A.PROJECT_ID,A.PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID,B.VALUE AS BU_START_DATE,C.VALUE AS BU_DURATION,D.VALUE AS BU_AMOUNT,E.VALUE AS PLUG FROM 
PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION A,
CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES B,
CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES C,
CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES D,
CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES E
WHERE 
A.TENANT_ID = '100' AND
B.MAP_ID = (SELECT MST_ATTRIBUTE_ID FROM `MST_TENANT_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES` 
WHERE LABEL='Budget Project Savings Start Date' AND 
TENANT_ID='100') AND
C.MAP_ID = (SELECT MST_ATTRIBUTE_ID FROM `MST_TENANT_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES` 
WHERE LABEL='Budget Savings Duration' AND 
TENANT_ID='100') AND
D.MAP_ID = (SELECT MST_ATTRIBUTE_ID FROM `MST_TENANT_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES` 
WHERE LABEL='Budget Annualized Savings' AND 
TENANT_ID='100') AND
E.MAP_ID = (SELECT MST_ATTRIBUTE_ID FROM `MST_TENANT_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES` 
WHERE LABEL='Plug' AND 
TENANT_ID='100')

GROUP BY A.PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID ORDER BY A.PROJECT_ID
```

Thanks.

Comment: check the execution plan - make sure the TENANT_ID field is indexed

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: try prepending `EXPLAIN` to the query and analyze results in your database management software

Comment: It would be much better if you could create an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for this 3 tables and share it.

The query becomes slow because RDBMS executes 4 selfjoins and only after that reduces the result. Too much work to do.

First try to join CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES and MST_ATTRIBUTE_ID and filter if after join. Then use this small inline view for further selfjoins.

Comment: Are you able to GROUP BY A.PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID and SELECT other *non-aggregate* fields except A.PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID? I beleave that SELECT or GROUP clause is wrong in above qury. Please confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are killing yourself with all the subqueries on the master_attribute_id table.  I have changed the query around do doing JOINs.  Start with your original "A" alias, but then do a JOIN to each attribute table on the same "A.TENANT_ID" (not fixed value) but ALSO per instance additionally AND ...LABEL = 'whatever'.  So each join gets to the custom attribute per the same tenant and label.  Now, from each of those, join to the attribute table by the MAP_ID.  So my aliases are associate with the "CAV" (custom_Addtribute_Values) table plus A, B, C, D as needed.  Therefore, you only need the actual tenant ID in the outermost WHERE clause.

Now, to help ensure optimization of the query, your MST_TENANT_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES table, I would have a covering index on (tenant_id, label, map_id).  For the Custom_Attributes_Values table, I would have an index on (map_id, value)

```
SELECT 
      A.PROJECT_ID,
      A.PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID,
      CAV_A.VALUE AS BU_START_DATE,
      CAV_B.VALUE AS BU_DURATION,
      CAV_C.VALUE AS BU_AMOUNT,
      E.VALUE AS PLUG 
   FROM 
      PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION A
         JOIN MST_TENANT_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES MT_A
            ON A.TENANT_ID = MT_A.TENANT_ID
            AND MT_A.LABEL = 'Budget Project Savings Start Date' 
            JOIN CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES A
               ON MT_A.MAP_ID = CAV_A.MAP_ID

         JOIN MST_TENANT_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES MT_B
            ON A.TENANT_ID = MT_B.TENANT_ID
            AND MA_B.LABEL = 'Budget Savings Duration' 
            JOIN CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES B
               ON MT_B.MAP_ID = CAV_B.MAP_ID

         JOIN MST_TENANT_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES MT_C
            ON A.TENANT_ID = MT_C.TENANT_ID
            AND MA_C.LABEL = 'Budget Annualized Savings'
            JOIN CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES C
               ON MT_C.MAP_ID = CAV_C.MAP_ID

         JOIN MST_TENANT_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES MT_D
            ON A.TENANT_ID = MT_D.TENANT_ID
            AND MA_D.LABEL = 'Plug' 
            JOIN CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES D
               ON MT_D.MAP_ID = CAV_D.MAP_ID
   WHERE 
      A.TENANT_ID = 100
   GROUP BY 
      A.PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID 
   ORDER BY 
      A.PROJECT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible something like this. Unfortunately didn't check it to ensure if it works.

```
SELECT 
      A.PROJECT_ID,
      A.PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID,
      IF(MT_A.LABEL='Budget Project Savings Start Date',CAV.VALUE,NULL) AS BU_START_DATE,
      IF(MT_A.LABEL='Budget Savings Duration',CAV.VALUE,NULL) AS BU_DURATION,
      IF(MT_A.LABEL='Budget Annualized Savings',CAV.VALUE,NULL) AS BU_AMOUNT,
      IF(MT_A.LABEL='Plug',CAV.VALUE,NULL) AS PLUG,
   FROM 
      PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION A
         JOIN MST_TENANT_CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES MT_A
            ON A.TENANT_ID = MT_A.TENANT_ID
            AND MT_A.LABEL in ('Budget Project Savings Start Date',
                               'Budget Savings Duration',
                               'Budget Annualized Savings',
                               'Plug')
            JOIN CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES CAV
               ON MT_A.MAP_ID = CAV.MAP_ID
   WHERE 
      A.TENANT_ID = 100
   GROUP BY 
      A.PROJECT_ID,A.PROJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION_ID 
   ORDER BY 
      A.PROJECT_ID
```